# Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 132120600 bytes)

Tags: php

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong and I don't know what to do so if someone could help, that'd be very helpful.

The error I get is as shows:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 132120600 bytes) in D:\wamp\www\testing\calendar.php on line 43
>   - https://.......com/cb71e74783b362ec2a55752c60dcbd32

And the code for the program is:

```
<?php
ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');
function build_calendar($month,$year){

    $daysOfWeek = array('Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday');
    $firstDayOfMonth = mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year);
    $numberDays = date('t'.$firstDayOfMonth);
    $dateComponents = getdate($firstDayOfMonth);
    $monthName = $dateComponents['month'];
    $dayOfWeek = $dateComponents['wday'];

    $dateToday = date('Y-m-d');

    $calendar = "<table class='table table-bordered'>";
    $calendar.= "<center><h2>$monthName $year</h2></center>";

    $calendar.="<tr>";

    foreach($daysOfWeek as $day){
        $calendar.="<th class='header'>$day</th>";
    }

    $calendar.= "</tr><tr>";

    if($dayOfWeek > 0){
        for($k=0;$k<$dayOfWeek;$k++){
            $calendar.="<td></td>";
        }
    }

    $currentDay = 1;
    $month = str_pad($month, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);

    while($currentDay <= $numberDays){

        if($dayOfWeek == 7){
            $dayOfWeek = 0;
            $calendar.="</tr><tr>";
        }

        $currentDayRel = str_pad($month, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
        $date = "$year-$month-$currentDayRel";
        $calendar.= "<td><h4>$currentDay</h4>";
        $calendar.="</td>";
        $currentDay++;
        $dayOfWeek++;
    }
    if($dayOfWeek != 7){
        $remainingDays = 7 - $dayOfWeek;
        for($i=0;$i<$remainingDays;$i++){
            $calendar.= "<td></td>";
        }
    }

    $calendar.="</tr>";
    $calendar.="</table>";

    echo $calendar;


}
?>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device,inital-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <?php
                $dateComponents = getdate();
                $month = $dateComponents['mon'];
                $year = $dateComponents['year'];
                echo build_calendar($month, $year)
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Line 43, as listed in the error message, is the line consisting of the code: `$calendar.= "<td><h4>$currentDay</h4>";`

Comment: it seems to be infinity loop. check value of `$numberDays` just before `while($currentDay <= $numberDays){`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the beginning of your script you are using a dot instead of comma on `date()`:

```
$numberDays = date('t'.$firstDayOfMonth);
```

While it actually should be:

```
$numberDays = date('t', $firstDayOfMonth);
```

This causes the while loop at line 34 to happens infinitely.